# Google Apps Script in Doc -- Looping through list_item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've got a google document consisting of a bulleted list like

- this
- is
- a
- test

I select this list and call the following function.

```
function TestFunction()
{
  var BullList =  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

    if (BullList) 
    {
      var elements = BullList.getRangeElements();
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
      {
        var element = elements[i];
        Logger.log(element.getElement().getType());
      }
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

[14-07-29 09:38:20:177 MDT] LIST_ITEM
[14-07-29 09:38:20:177 MDT] LIST_ITEM
[14-07-29 09:38:20:178 MDT] LIST_ITEM
[14-07-29 09:38:20:179 MDT] TEXT

What I don't understand is why the last item shows up as a TEXT object instead of a LIST_ITEM.  This always occurs on the last item of the selection, regardless of whether or not it is the last item in the list or not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you get that result because the last item of you list is not selected entirely, maybe there is just a space or something that is not in the selection.

If any part of a list item is partially selected it is identified as text .

demo below :

[image]

example with invisible partial selection :

[image]

Comment: No that's not it.  I make sure it's completely selected.

Comment: could you try to add something after the list (like I did in my example) and recheck the selection stopping right before the "text" part and starting from the top left ? I'm quite sure I'm right.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  I've made sure that the last item in the list has no spaces after it.  I've also added spaces and made sure they are selected.  No matter what I do the last selected is always text.

Comment: every list item has a space at its end added automatically, look at the screen capture in my answer : I did not type the spaces after each item, they came automatically. This occurs also on the last item. I suggested to add something below so that you can drag the whole list and stop right before the following item.

Comment: Hmm...another experiment.  If I select all in the document, I correctly get LIST_ITEM.  If I select with the mouse starting well below the list, I do not.

Comment: of course, in that case (entire doc) the last item is entirely selected... I know this seems weird but my explanation is right... unpleasant but right ;-) Also : there MUST be something after the last list item otherwise the last item is always "text"

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I removed my edit, no need to add something below... it is possible to select the last space without it... btw, please consider marking this as answered. thx

Answer (score 0):

I believe `list_item` is a `paragraph` associated with a `listID`, and needs to be inclusive of `\r` to be considered a paragraph.  Otherwise is_partial == True
Try including the next line (without any actual characters) in your selection.